# Error: "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax. ". Problem in the .env or PDO?

Tags: php, sql, pdo, localhost, slim

I am fixing someone else's code and am getting a

> "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax" error.

My first thought was I didn't install slim correctly, but installing again didn't make any difference. So maybe the problem is in the .env file or the PDO. Can anyone help?

[image]

PDO:

```
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Model;

use PDO;

abstract class PdoModel
{
   protected static $connection;

   protected function getConnection() : PDO
   {
       // Singleton pattern to use just 1 DB connection for all database calls
       if (!self::$connection) {
           self::$connection = new PDO('mysql:host=' . getenv('DB_HOST') . ';dbname=' . getenv('DB_DATABASE'), getenv('DB_USERNAME'), getenv('DB_PASSWORD'));
           self::$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
           self::$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
       }

       return self::$connection;
   }
}
```

.env:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=exam
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
DB_PORT=3306
```

first part of eventmodel:

```
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Model;

use DateTime;

class EventModel extends PdoModel
{
 public function getEvents() : array
 {
     $query = "SELECT e.id,e.name,e.description,e.event_manager_id,em.name as event_manager_name ,
     e.company_name,DATE_FORMAT(datetime,'%d-%m-%Y') as date,DATE_FORMAT(datetime,'%H:%i') as time,
      e.maximum_amount_of_guests as guests,
               FROM event e LEFT JOIN event_manager em ON (em.id = e.event_manager_id) ORDER BY date DESC";
     $statement = $this->getConnection()->prepare($query);
     $statement->execute();
     return $statement->fetchAll();
 }
```

Any suggestions are welcome. I have no idea left what the problem might be.

Comment: u have an issue in code not in .env

Comment: The error message is a great troubleshooting tool. In your case, it says that there was a syntax error near `FROM EVENT`. Looking at your query, there's an extra comma right before FROM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query you have an extra comma before `FROM`

**Correct Query:**

```
SELECT 
    e.id,
    e.name,
    e.description,
    e.event_manager_id,
    em.name as event_manager_name,
    e.company_name,
    DATE_FORMAT(datetime,'%d-%m-%Y') as date,
    DATE_FORMAT(datetime,'%H:%i') as time,
    e.maximum_amount_of_guests as guests
FROM event e 
LEFT JOIN event_manager em ON (em.id = e.event_manager_id) 
ORDER BY date DESC
```

**Error in your query:**

You have an issue here:

```
e.maximum_amount_of_guests as guests, // this will generate error
               FROM event e
```

`1064` clearly show you, you have an issue in your query not .env file.

**[Server Error Reference:](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-error-reference.html)**

Comment: question should be closed as a typo

Comment: @JayBlanchard: hi, how are you, yes u r right, its typo and will not help in future, thatsway i added some extra stuff related to server error and 1064..

Comment: Thank you so much! This took me days. I couldn't find the mistake in the query. I am new to PHP and Google told me it should be a problem in the .env file then. The code had a .env issue before and that gave me the simular error. Hence the confusion. So thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.id,e.name,e.description,e.event_manager_id,em.name as event_manager_name ,
     e.company_name,DATE_FORMAT(datetime,'%d-%m-%Y') as date,DATE_FORMAT(datetime,'%H:%i') as time,
      e.maximum_amount_of_guests as guests
               FROM event e LEFT JOIN event_manager em ON (em.id = e.event_manager_id) ORDER BY date DESC
```

You had a syntax error in your query. The error was pretty straight forward to that. Your env file is fine.